# How to calculate the VCPU in Azure for On-premise VM migration

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I wish to run a web server on Azure.

My On-premise VM has the below configuration

1. CPU Speed: 2,593
2. CPU Count: 4
3. CPU Cores: 1

what would be the equivalent VCPU in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the CPU count would indicate the number of physical processors and the cores with be the number of cores within the processor but this looks backwards.  I would expect to see 1 processor with 4 cores instead of 4 x single core processors.  Either way I would see this as 4 vCPU in Azure.